# Divide 40 eggs over 7 days, use odd numbers

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

I ve been asked to solve this riddle;
Eat 40 eggs in 7 days.
Minimum 1 egg a day.
Only use odd numbers...

Answer (score 4):

Monday to Friday, eat 5 and 1/7th eggs. Saturday and Sunday, eat 7 and 1/7th eggs.

Now we all know that fractions are not odd numbers, however, the question doesn't state "Only *eat* odd numbers of eggs", it simply asks us to *use* odd numbers, and the above solution uses only 1,5 and 7: all odd numbers.

Comment: As a bonus is this answer written by an odd number :P

Answer (score 3):

Since it's (obviously) impossible mathematically we have to go lateral.

I think everyone can agree that

> 34 eggs is a very **odd** number of eggs to eat in a day

So we just eat

> 1 every mon-saturday, going by the mathematical definition of odd. Then 34 on sunday, going by the definition in the dictionary
> **1. Deviating from what is ordinary, usual, or expected;**

Comment: This is the right answer to a very similar old chestnut from one of the old classic puzzling books (can't remember which right now).

Comment: @DrXorile I've seen it with cubes of sugar in tea.

Comment: That's the one I've seen

Answer (score 2):

Using only odd numbers:

- Eat 1 egg on Monday
- Eat 1 egg on Tuesday
- Eat 1 egg on Wednesday
- Eat 1 egg on Thursday
- Eat 1 egg on Friday
- Eat 1 egg on Saturday
- Eat 1 egg on Sunday morning
- Eat 33 eggs on Sunday evening

:-)

Comment: You know, speaking of that, 34 itself is a pretty odd number of eggs to be eating in one day...

Answer (score 1):

The simple mathematical answer is that it is impossible. Adding an odd number of odd numbers (7 odd numbers) will always result in an odd number. As 40 is even, it is impossible to add 7 odd numbers to get an even number.

On a lateral thinking attempt, eat 5 eggs the first 4 days, and 7 eggs the last 3. You will have eaten a total of 41 eggs, but you will have eaten 40 eggs in 7 days. You just so happened to have eaten an extra egg (and gotten very sick).

Comment: Mathematical is this of course correct (impossible) but it will be something like you lateral thinking attempt :)